# how can i set a select menu in jquery mobile to the local storage?

Tags: jquery-mobile, select

I have a select menu in jquery mobile and I want to set it to the local storage and then later to get the values from it. This is so if a user selects a car it will be able to delete the car from the list?

Does anyone know how to accomplish this?

```
<div data-role="fieldcontain">
    <label for="select1">Choose a car to rent:</label>
    <select name="select1" id="select1" onchange="selectvalue(this.value);">
        <option value="97-113-13">Avenger </option>
        <option value="97-225-13">Caravan </option>
        <option value="97-112-13">Focus </option>
        <option value="97-119-13">Escape</option>
        <option value="97-226-13">E 350</option>
        <option value="97-227-13">Mustang</option>
        <option value=" 97-118-13">Wrangler</option>
        <option value="97-223-13">Grand Cherokee</option>
        <option value="97-111-13">Picanto</option>
        <option value="97-114-13">Galant</option>
        <option value="97-115-13">Altima</option>
        <option value="97-116-13">Juke</option>
        <option value="97-222-13">Corolla</option>
    </select>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

> **[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/ezanker/XS37k/)**

```
    <div data-role="fieldcontain">
        <label for="selCar">Select car:</label>
        <select name="selCar" id="selCar">
            <option value="97-113-13">Avenger</option>
            <option value="97-225-13">Caravan</option>
            <option value="97-112-13">Focus</option>
            <option value="97-119-13">Escape</option>
            <option value="97-226-13">E 350</option>
            <option value="97-227-13">Mustang</option>
            <option value=" 97-118-13">Wrangler</option>
            <option value="97-223-13">Grand Cherokee</option>
            <option value="97-111-13">Picanto</option>
            <option value="97-114-13">Galant</option>
            <option value="97-115-13">Altima</option>
            <option value="97-116-13">Juke</option>
            <option value="97-222-13">Corolla</option>
        </select>
    </div>
```

Each time you submit the form, get the currently selected value from the select menu and save it to localStorage.  Each time the page is created, read the value from localStorage and then remove it from the options list:

```
$(document).on("pagecreate", "#page1", function(){
     RemovePreviouslySelected();

    $("#btnSubmit").on("click", function(){
        var selVal = $("#selCar").val();
        localStorage.setItem("selectedCar", selVal);
    });
});

function RemovePreviouslySelected(){
    var prev = localStorage.getItem("selectedCar");
    if (prev){
        $("#selCar option").each(function(index){
            if ($(this).prop("value") == prev){
                $(this).remove();
                return;
            }
        });   
    }
}
```